# PHP table in collapse

Tags: php, html-table

I'm having trouble to collapse the next row in table. My code works only for the first row of the table where ever I click the collapse button.

[image: clicked first row]

[image: clicked 4th row. still the collapse happen at first row]

Code :

```
<table id="yourEvent" class="table table-hover">
                    <thead>  
                            <tr>    
                                <td style="text-align: center" width="20px"><strong>No.</strong></td>
                                <td><strong>Attendee Name</strong></td> 
                            </tr>  
                    </thead>
                        <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultAttendeeList))
                        { ?>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="counterCell"  style="text-align: center" width="20px"></td>

                                <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-xs bg-maroon" style="width: 20px" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#divCol"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>&emsp;<?php echo $row['fullname'];?>

                                    <div class="collapse" id="divCol">
                                        <table>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>Address: <?php echo $row['address']; ?></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>Contact: 0<?php echo $row['contact']; ?></td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>

                                </td>

                            </tr>
                        <?php } ?>  
                        </tbody>  

                  </table>
```

Comment: `id`s are supposed to be unique, yet you are using `id="divCol"` in a loop. so you have `count($resultAttendeeList)` number of the same `id`. So it is only recognizing the 1st row, not any subsequent rows.

Comment: Thank you! this works! i use echo the person id inside and it works like charm

Answer (score 1):

You are using **same ID for multiple divs** in your loop. You can create incremental int variable and concatenate in your div IDs.

try this code: added `$ctr` variable increments through loop. Also, you should start your loop after the `<tbody>` tag.

```
        <tbody> 
    <?php $ctr=1; 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultAttendeeList))
                                {    ?>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="counterCell"  style="text-align: center" width="20px"></td>

                                        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-xs bg-maroon" style="width: 20px" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#divCol_<?=$ctr?>"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>&emsp;<?php echo $row['fullname'];?>

                                            <div class="collapse" id="divCol_<?=$ctr?>">
                                                <table>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>Address: <?php echo $row['address']; ?></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>Contact: 0<?php echo $row['contact']; ?></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                            </div>

                                        </td>

                                    </tr>
                                <?php  $ctr=$ctr+1; } ?>
```

Comment: tried your code but it works just the same. Still only open the first row

Comment: @ktato you can shorthand `$ctr=$ctr+1;` to just `$ctr++;`

Comment: @Eefy.Thanks for trying my code though did not solve the problem. hehe :)

Comment: @ktaro you set the value of `$ctr` to 1 in your loop, so it will always assign `divCol_1` to each div. Move that variable outside of the loop and it should work fine.

Comment: Hi @ThomasScheffer. Oh yeah! I didn't see that. Thanks for pointing me out.@Eefy maybe that's the reason why my code did not work. I just updated my answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this is complete code. Please give dynamic id. make sure when you process any jquery/javascript operation, divid should always unique. Otherwise event will not bind for all element.

```
<?php
$servername = "host";
$username = "user";
$password = "pass";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, 'testdb');

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY ID limit 5";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

// Numeric array
//$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id="yourEvent" class="table table-hover">
            <thead>  
                <tr>    
                    <td style="text-align: center" width="20px"><strong>No.</strong></td>
                    <td><strong>Attendee Name</strong></td> 
                </tr>  
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php
                $j = 1;
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                    ?>                
                    <tr>
                        <td class="counterCell"  style="text-align: center" width="20px"><?php echo $j; ?></td>

                        <td>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs bg-maroon" style="width: 20px" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#divCol_<?php echo $j; ?>">
                                <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                            </button>&emsp;<?php echo $row['EMP_FULLNAME']; ?>

                            <div class="collapse" id="divCol_<?php echo $j; ?>">
                                <table>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Address: <?php echo $row['EMP_ADDRESS']; ?></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Contact: 0<?php echo $row['EMP_MOBILE']; ?></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>

                        </td>

                    </tr>
                    <?php
                    $j++;
                }
                ?>  
            </tbody>  

        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```